# Calling VBScript from JavaScript or vice versa?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

Is it possible to call a [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) function from a [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) call, or alternately call JavaScript from a VBScript call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if your main script is a [Windows Script File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15x4407c.aspx) (WSF).

WSF files can include other script files and execute code from multiple engines.

Comment: This isn't the only way to do it, though, as evidenced by other answers.  Misleading.

Answer (score 6):

**Calling a VBScript function from Javascript**

Your VBScript:

```
Function myVBFunction()
  ' here comes your vbscript code
End Function
```

Your Javascript:

```
function myJavascriptFunction(){
  myVBFunction();           // calls the vbs function
}
window.onload = myJavascriptFunction;
```

**Calling a Javascript function from VBScript**

```
Function myVBFunction()
  myJavascriptFunction()  
End Function
```

Comment: The link you edited in has *nothing at all* to do with the topic of this post, and seems very spammy as a result. Do not repost it. Also, according to the FAQ on self-promotion, you must disclose whenever posting a link to your own website, which you failed to do.

Comment: -1 this js file  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DxAqnQix   gives this error http://i.imgur.com/Zpy92I4.png  and this vbs file gives this error http://i.imgur.com/85enHzP.png

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible within HTA's by specifying the language when the function is called, like this:

```
<input id="renameIcon" 
       name="renameIcon" 
       type="image" 
       src="images/rename.ico" 
       onclick=renameUser() 
       onmouseover='vbscript: if showStat <> "busy" Then call showStatus(button4.title)' 
       onmouseout='vbscript: if showStat <> "busy" Then call showStatus("")'>
```