# Embed VBScript in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have a problem with embedding a VBScript to my Javascript in a `.js` file. I want to place a `title` to my alert boxes, so I want to use the VBScript.

I have a `.js` file, and this is what I want to insert in my `.js` file.

```
<script language="VBScript">
Function makeMsgBox(tit, mess, icon, buts, defs, mode)
    butVal = icon + buts + defs + mode
    makeMsgBox = MsgBox(mess, butVal, tit)
End Function
</script>
```

But it gives me an error, I think it does not allow me to insert a VBScript in my Javascript file.

Comment: I suppose you could try to generate the `script` tag and contents for the VBScript with Javascript, but why not just put it in it's own file with the appropriate filetype? You could of course use something like a [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead, which would probably be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the script declaration `<script language="VBScript">` in a .js file. You also cannot have a VBScript function in a .js file.

You can try creating a [.wsf file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File) within which you can use both JavaScript an VBScript.

I am not clear about what all the parameters in your function are doing but here's how you can use both JavaScript and VBScript in the same Windows Script File and even call each other's functions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<package>
    <job>   
        <script language="VBScript">        
            Function makeMsgBox(tit,mess,buts)
                makeMsgBox = MsgBox (mess,buts,tit)
            End Function
        </script>   

        <script language="JavaScript">
            var YES_NO_CANCEL = 3;
            makeMsgBox("VBScript message box", "Calling from JavaScript", YES_NO_CANCEL);
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you @Abbas, its working already i can set title already but the VBScript is always present at the title bar.. is there a way to remove it?

Comment: The title bar could say:  "VBScript:Hello there"   can I make it to just "Hello"?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying that  your .js file with a VB function working? In case it is, can show what you have written in that file?

Comment: @Abbas - The reason tinks is using VBScript is because (I suppose in IE) it allows him to set a `MsgBox` window handle title text.

Comment: The VBScript function that I have, I placed in my .html file then called it in my .js file. Its working fine now. Its just that "VBSCript" is always present in the title.

Comment: @Jared yes correct.. I wanted to edit the title of my alert box. You have other suggestions using javascript to go about with it? :(

Comment: @tinks - When you say "working", you do mean in IE only, right? What about all the other browsers? And I didn't know that JS could use VBScript. That's actually surprising.

Comment: @Abbas - I see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466059/calling-vbscript-from-javascript-or-vice-versa

Comment: @Tinks Since you are calling a VBScript function from a Javascript function, the browser will append "VBScript" before the title. I don't thin there's a way around it.

Comment: @Abbas  thank you. I found another alternative though.. http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/  - using jQuery.

Comment: It works in the site but when I downloaded, its not working :( it says "jQuery is not defined" :(

Comment: @Tinks Viewing the source of your link, I can see that the following 4 files need to be downloaded and included:  
  

<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  

<!-- Core files -->
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />


Have you downloaded and included them?

Comment: @Abbas i think the draggable is only for dragging the alert box.. didnt quite see the dependencies..

Comment: @Abbas i could not find the dependencies that you pointed out.. do you still have the link of the list? thank you

Comment: @Tinks I went through the link that you posted and click on the demo link within it, here's the URL: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/. Go through the source code of this demo and you will see the dependencies that you mentioned. While the "jquery.ui.draggable.js" file is not needed, I think you will need the rest. Download these files to your disk, make sure the paths are correct and then try the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include VBScript inside your .js file. You have to add this script inside your html code.

```
<script type="text/vbscript" >
set objSHL=createobject("wscript.shell") 
strMsg= objSHL.popup("message",timetoclose,"title",icon)
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).