# Executing a javascript function on Visual Basic

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have a JS function in a web application of an IP camera. This JS function allows the user to take a photo (snapshot) and store it. What I want to do is to implement a function on Visual Basic (associated to a button) that either calls this function on JS or makes click on the snapshot button of the web application. Is it that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling VBScript from JavaScript or vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466059/calling-vbscript-from-javascript-or-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the VBScript is handling the code for the onclick events, you can have the vbscript activate the javascript. [Click here for a link switching between these two languages.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466059/calling-vbscript-from-javascript-or-vice-versa)

Where the difference matters is, is this a purely client based website or a server based website. Are you using vbscript crutched against ASP or just against the clients browser?

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script language="JavaScript" >
function jsfunction()
{
  alert("Hello")
}

</script>
<%
Response.Write "Calling =" jsfunction() "."
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Above source code originally from -> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456985/executing-a-javascript-function-on-visual-basic)